# Is it possible folder based configuration in a Typescript project ? Multi tsconfig.json or something else

Tags: typescript

I would like to set

```
"noImplicitAny": true
```

in **tsconfig.json** only for a specified folder.

Out of the folder it must be **false** again.

Comment: This [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8855) argues a similar case to yours -except it is on files not folders. There are no direct ways but workarounds, yet maybe it can help.

Comment: It seems like labeled as "Won't Fix

Answer (score 0):

you might extend your default config:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "noImplicitAny": false
}
```

but it is project/module based, not directory based.

Comment: Should I run command tsc -p . twice since it is project based ?

Comment: Like tsc -p . && tsc -p ./dir1/dir2

Comment: @codelovesme not sure on this, depends on the desired results. Had to test this first

Comment: I have tested already, before asking the question. But that wasn't the solution